# Sort files by basename

Tags: sorting, find

After a find, I'd like to sort the output by the basename (the number of directories is unknown). I know this can be done by splitting the basename from the dirname and sorting that, but I'm specifically looking for something where it's not necessary to modify the data before the sort. Something like `sort --field-separator='/' -k '-1'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with a solution of simply moving the base name to the start of the string, sorting, and moving it back. Not really what I was hoping for, but it works even with weirdzo file names.

Answer (score 1):

For this task, I'd turn to perl and the use of a custom sort function. Save the perl code below as basename_sort.pl, chmod it 0755, then you can execute a command such as you've requested, as:

```
find | grep "\.php" | ./basename_sort.pl
```

Of course, you'll want to move that utility somewhere if you're doing it very often. Better yet, I'd also recommend wrapping a function around it within your .bashrc file. (staying on topic, sh code for that not included)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my @lines = <STDIN>;
@lines = sort basename_sort @lines;
foreach( @lines ) {
   print $_;
}

sub basename_sort() {
   my @data1 = split('/', $a);
   my @data2 = split('/', $b);
   my $name1 = $data1[@data1 - 1];
   my $name2 = $data2[@data2 - 1];
   return lc($name1) cmp lc($name2);
}
```

Comment: p.s. yes, that basename_sort() function could be abbreviated or obviated with an anonymous block and other perl syntactic mysticism.. but, it's all spelled out strict and case-insensitive for optimal clarity/simplicity

Comment: Though basename does not imply case-insensitive normally.

Answer (score 0):

This can be written shorter.

```
find | perl -e 'print sort{($p=$a)=~s!.*/!!;($q=$b)=~s!.*/!!;$p cmp$q}<>'
```

Comment: exactly the kind of mysticism vs pragmatism issue I mentioned, because that's quite a mouthful. kudos on it working, but I'd still like to see an sh function for it, as well